# 4 cards are drawn(with returns) from a deck of 52 cards, what is the probability that all the cards are different suits?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The answer: $({1\over4})^44!$ why is this, i would think the answer is: *$${\binom{13}{1}^4\over52^4}$$*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you take hearts first. Probability of that $=\frac{13}{52}=\frac{1}{4}$
Then take a different specific one (say spades). Prob - $=\frac{13}{52}=\frac{1}{4}$
Another specific one (say diamonds). Prob - $=\frac{13}{52}=\frac{1}{4}$.
Another specific one (say clubs). Prob - $=\frac{13}{52}=\frac{1}{4}$.
Now probability that all of this happens in this order is $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4$.

But we have to add the probabilities of it happening in different orders -
hearts-diamonds-spades-clubs
hearts-clubs-diamonds-spades
etc. ($4!-1$ in total)

So our answer is $\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4}_{4!\text{ times}}=4!\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4$.

We multiply probabilities when the events happen at the same time.
We add when one happens OR another one happens OR...

Answer (score 1):

Draw the first card.  So far, so good: no duplicate suite!
Draw the second card; it is a different suite with probability 3/4.
Assuming no duplicate suite so far, draw the third card; it is a different suite than the first two with probability 2/4.
Assuming no duplicate suite so far, draw the third card; it is a different suite than the first three with probability 1/4.

Multiply.